# Why using grep with screen doesn't work correctly?

Tags: bash

I want to check is screen with my server is on the screen list. I use this script but it's sucks and don't work

```sh
#!/bin/bash

SERWER="test_start.sh"
SCRN="testMinecraft"

if ! [[ screen -ls | grep $SCRN ]]; then
        /root/testser/$SERWER
fi
```

idk what i need to change there to start this script

EDIT:
I change it to this, but it still doesn't work

```sh
#!/bin/bash

SERWER="test_start.sh"
SCRN=`screen -ls | grep "testowyscreen" | wc -l`

if ! [ $screen -eq 1  ]; then
        echo "there is nothing";
        /root/testser/$SERWER
fi
```

output: `./test_restart.sh: line 6: [: -eq: unary operator expected`

Comment: Remove `[[` and `]]` or `[` and `]`.

Comment: Paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

bash supports `[[` and `]]` and you need to place exclamation mark inside the bracers, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERWER="test_start.sh"
SCRN=`screen -ls | grep "testowyscreen" | wc -l`

if [[ ! $screen -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "there is nothing";
    /root/testser/$SERWER
fi
```

P.S.
`` is deprecated you should use $()